# How to use jQuery Datatable in asp.net core mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, datatables

I donwload [jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/download/) and the files I put it in my `wwwroot` folder. This is the structure of `wwwroot` folder:

```
 -wwwroot
             -css
             -DataTable 
               -DataTables-1.10.21
                  -css
                  -images
                  -js
               -datatables.css
               -datatables.js
             -IMG
             -js
             -lib
```

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I inserted :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DataTable/datatables.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="~/DataTable/datatables.js"></script>
```

to use jQuery Datatable.

But I can't use it in my view page. This is what I try to do in my view page :

```
 *<table class="table table-hover" id="tblmissioni">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
                </th>
                .....
             </tr>
        </thead>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tblmissioni").DataTable(
                {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Missioni/Missioni",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        { "data": "asdasd" },
                        ---I have 45 colums----
                    ]
                });
        }
    </script>*
```

Is it correct to do like this or not? I don't know if my  `<link>` and `<script>` are correct in `_Layout.cshtml`

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttwe1.png)

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How specifically does this fail?  Check the browser's development tools.  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

Comment: Here are the errors : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttwe1.png

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your code.  DataTables depends on that library.  It also looks like you have a syntax error to address.  (You never close the call to `.ready()`)